# Marking some parameters of the route as optional

Tags: c#, azure-functions

Imagine I have an `Azure function` like this:

```
[FunctionName("MakeMeRich")]
public async Task<IActionResult> MakeMeRich(
[HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", Route = "createmoney/printdate/{printDate}/moneycurrency/{moneyCurrency}/moneyamount/{moneyAmount}")] HttpRequest req,
    ILogger log, string printDate, string moneyCurrency, decimal moneyAmount)
```

If I pass all the `parameters` and their values, it works alright.
The problem is **I want to make the last two parameters to be optional**. How do I do that?

I have tried these approaches below with no success:

```
moneycurrency?/{moneyCurrency}
moneycurrency/{moneyCurrency?}
string? moneyCurrency
```

Comment: I see you have posted the same [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76324048/declaring-a-route-with-one-required-parameter-and-multiple-optional-query-string/76328905#76328905), does this answer your question or you are looking for anything else?

Comment: @Harshitha well, nobody answered this question for a while so I had to come up with my own solution and I had a question about that solution so I had asked that question. But I still don't know if for the real problem I had which is this current question , if there is a better way or not.

Comment: @MidTown When a parameter is marked as optional in the route template, it must still be included in the URL, but with an empty value if it is not being used.

The main issue with the URL breaking point at moneycurrency even we set it as optional. Since, the URL breaks at the point it's not possible to route other URL endponits. We can set single function with 2 URL's with optional parameters.
I tried [this](https://i.imgur.com/8EVOv0p.png) code
and got [results](https://i.imgur.com/Id6e615.png) through [URL1](https://i.imgur.com/wtIiFWm.png) and [URL2](https://i.imgur.com/tspIbBf.png).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have referred this  [Azure Functions HTTP trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook-trigger?pivots=programming-language-csharp&tabs=python-v2%2Cin-process%2Cfunctionsv2) .

- Since URL breaks or do not continue if the optimal parameters are present in the middle from @Kamali point. Thank your commits @Kamali.
- One of the solutions is to use the optional parameters at the end.

The route below

```
createmoney/printdate/{printDate}/moneycurrency/{moneyCurrency}/moneyamount/{moneyAmount}
```

should be changed to

```
createmoney/printdate/{printDate}/moneycurrency/moneyamount/{moneyCurrency?}/ {moneyAmount?}
```

**(or)**

Try this

```
example.com/path?mandatory=value1&optional1=value2&optional2=value3
```

**Sample code :**

```cs
[FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = "sample/{param1?}/{param2?}")] HttpRequest req,
            string param1,
            string param2,
            ILogger log)
{

   log.LogInformation("A request was handled by a C# HTTP trigger function.");
```

**Output:**

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]