# Declaring a route with one required parameter and multiple optional query strings

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, azure-functions, webapi

I don't have much experience in declaring routes so what I want might even be invalid but I am thinking of having a route like this:

```
givememoney/printdate/2023-05-23&currency=USD&amonut=alot&forwhom=me,mom,dad
```

where `printdate` and some value for it like `2023-05-23` is always **required**.
but the rest of it is **optional**.

First: Is this valid?

Second: If it is valid, how can I declare such a route? Here is what I tried but it is wrong.

```
[FunctionName("GiveMeMoney")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GiveMeMoney(
[HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", Route = "givememoney/{printdate}/{optional?}")] HttpRequest req, ILogger log, string printdate, string? optional)
{
    // .... stuff ...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> First: Is this valid?

Yes, this is Valid and below is my code:

Function1.cs:

```
using System.Net;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace FunctionApp24
{
    public class Function1
    {
        private readonly ILogger _logger;

        public Function1(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<Function1>();
        }

        [Function("Function1")]
        public HttpResponseData Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", Route = "emo/{date}")] HttpRequestData req, FunctionContext context,
            string date, string? Sur)
        {
            var logger = context.GetLogger("Function1");

            var q = req.Url.Query;
            var qp = Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities.QueryHelpers.ParseQuery(q);
            string name = qp["name"];            
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Sur))
            {
                logger.LogInformation($"SurName: {Sur}");
            }

            logger.LogInformation($"name:{name}");
            

            var response = req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            response.WriteString("Completed Rithwik");

            return response;
        }
    }
}
```

Here name is required parameter and Sur is Optional Parameter.

> Second: If it is valid, how can I declare such a route?

Firstly, to call only required then use below:

```
http://localhost:7115/api/emo/2023-05-25?name=Rithwik
```

[image]

Output:

[image]

Optional Calling :

```
http://localhost:7115/api/emo/2023-05-25?name=Rithwik&Sur=Bojja
```

[image]

Output:

[image]